# How do I make Hydra's multirun sweeper test multiple repetitions of each condition?

Tags: python, fb-hydra

Hydra enables [sweeping combinations of parameters](https://hydra.cc/docs/tutorials/basic/running_your_app/multi-run/), for example:

```
python my_app.py --multirun db=mysql,postgresql schema=warehouse,support,school
```

will test six different conditions.

Is there a principled way of conducting multiple runs of each condition (other than adding a dummy factor)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical purpose of doing something like this is to run non-deterministic functions. The canonical way is to add a random seed parameter and to use it to initialize the random subsystem(s).

Note that you can use range to make this shorter, something like:

```bash
$ python my_app.py --multirun a=a1,a2 b=b1,b2,b3 'seed=range(1,5)'
```

If you want more sophisticated handling of the sweep, take a look at the Sweeper plugins (e.g the [Optuna sweeper](https://hydra.cc/docs/plugins/optuna_sweeper/)).